# How To auto enable checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi  i have four check box and i want if i click one check box then other check box auto checked and if i unchecked that check box then it should be unchecked.
i am using this  but it is  not working

```
  <p class="contact">
    <input type="checkbox" name="PlanA" value="A"onchange="document.getElementById('a2').checked=!this.checked;"><label for="PlanA"><span style="font-weight:bold">PlanA</span></label><br>
    <input name="PlanA" type="hidden" value=0 />
  </p>
  <p class="contact">
    <input type="checkbox" name="AndroidApps" id="a2" value=1><label for="AndroidApps"><span style="font-weight:bold">AndroidApps</span></label><br>
    <input name="AndroidApps" type="hidden" value=0 />
  </p>
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `onchange="document.getElementById('a2').checked=this.checked;"`

Comment: can i pass multiple  check box id in getElementById()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/61/)

```
onchange="document.getElementById('a2').checked=this.checked;"
```

See here [fiddle2 multiple checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/62/)

Comment: can i pass multiple check box id in getElementById()

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("input[name=PlanA]").change(function(){

$("#a2").attr("checked",this.checked);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eVj8V/5/)

Answer (score 2):

try  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y7nWg/)

```
$("input[name=PlanA]").change(function(){

$("#a2").attr("checked",this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, pure javascript
Define id for first checkbox as a1

```
  onchange="(document.getElementById('a1').checked) ? (document.getElementById('a2').checked = true) : (document.getElementById('a2').checked = false);">
```

Answer (score 1):

A label can be bound to an element either by using the "form" attribute.

HTML

```
<p class="contact">
   <input type="checkbox" id="PlanA" name="PlanA" value="A">
   <label for="PlanA">PlanA</label>
   <input name="PlanA" type="hidden" value=0 />
</p>
<p class="contact">
   <input type="checkbox" name="AndroidApps" id="AndroidApps" value=1>
   <label for="AndroidApps">AndroidApps</label>
   <input name="AndroidApps" type="hidden" value=0 />
</p>
```

JS

```
$('#PlanA').change(function(){$('#AndroidApps').attr("checked", this.checked);})
```

CSS

```
.contact label {font-weight: bold }
```